# how to validate and execute an ethereum transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain

I'm confused about how to validate a transaction in Ethereum.
In fact, according to my simple knowledge, I know that the transaction row is signed and then the signature of the transaction is broadcast to the network so:

How the transaction is validated while only the signature (without the transaction row) is published in the network?
can anyone corrects or answers me?

Comment: what do you mean by transaction row? do you mean raw?

Comment: I mean the transaction in clear

Comment: After several researches, I realized that the transaction (tx row: nonce, gasprice, gaslimit, to, value, data) and the signature (the values v,r,s) are both broadcast to the network. Then the transaction signature can be verified and validated to realize that the transaction is sent by a legitimate user as well as the transaction has not been tampered.

Answer (score 1):

The validation involves checking the signature of the transaction and verify that you have enough funds to pay for gas and any transfered value (ethereum uses accounts, which not the case for Bitcoin). If this is verified the transaction will eventually be included in a block and that will be all.

This article gives details of how transactions are initiated verified and included in the block: https://medium.com/blockchannel/life-cycle-of-an-ethereum-transaction-e5c66bae0f6e

Hope this helps.